# import query from Azure Data Explorer to PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, azure-data-explorer, kql

I am trying to import K queries in Azure Data Explorer to PowerBI. When I copy and the queries inot Advanced Editor in PowerBI. I get the error code: **Token Comma Expected**

I need help on how to clear the error and to use the queries in PowerBI.

I have the query as below:

```
let MTNList = externaldata
(Oveid:string,vendor:string,product:string,EtinName:string,dateAdded:string,description:string,action:string,dueDate:string,notes:stri
ng) [@https://www.mtd.com/sites/default/files/csv/people_isages.csv\] with (format="csv", ignoreFirstRecord=True)

 

let MTNOveid = MTNList
| project Oveid;DeviceTvmSoftwareVulnerabilities
| where OveId in (MTNOveid)
| summarize Devices = dcount(DeviceId) by OveId
| sort by Devices desc
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Power BI "Advanced Editor" is for [Power Query M formula language](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/), not KQL.

This is how a Power BI GUI setup for ADX query looks like:

[image: Power BI GUI]

This is the representation in Power Query:

```
let
    Source = AzureDataExplorer.Contents("https://help.kusto.windows.net/", "Samples", "print ""Hello World""#(lf)| count", [MaxRows=null, MaxSize=null, NoTruncate=null, AdditionalSetStatements=null])
in
    Source
```

P.S.

If you define your queries as functions, e.g.

```
.create-or-alter function f1 () {print 1}

.create-or-alter function f2 () {print 2}

.create-or-alter function f3 () {print 3}
```

You can import them all in one step using the Power BI UI

[image: Import Functions]